# ms-release-management and release-management tags are getting confused

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

There's the tag [release-management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/release-management), which applies to the general practice of tools and methodologies for managing software releases.

The problem is, Microsoft released a tool to manage releases. They called it "Release Management". I made a tag a while back to handle the incoming questions around the tool, called [ms-release-management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ms-release-management). This turned out to be a naming mistake: people don't seem to be seeing the tag -- they ask questions tagged [release-management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/release-management), and that's fine, because it totally applies to their question! But they're missing the fact that a tag for this specific application exists, so the questions tend to go unanswered, or less-answered. I periodically go through and retag appropriately, but that's an untenable solution.

What is the commonly accepted way to handle this? I was thinking of creating a new tag ([release-management-visual-studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/release-management-visual-studio) or something that puts the product name up front), then retagging everything. There are less than a hundred questions, so now is the time to fix the problem!

Since there's been limited feedback on this issue, I'd like to make a formal request:
**Please rename the [ms-release-management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ms-release-management) tag to [release-management-tfs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/release-management-tfs)**. This will disambiguate the tag by putting the product name up front and distinguish it from the general [release-management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/release-management) tag by indicating that it's part of the Microsoft TFS product.

Comment: kill release management, that's the only way.

Comment: Not sure I agree. The release-management tag has value. It's just about a specific subdivision of ALM, just like you might tag a question about branching strategies with Git with [branching]. One tag is for a practice, one is for a specific tool around the practice. Plus, the release-management tag has about 5x as many questions.

Comment: Well, I'm seeing it from a purely resources distribution point of view. The tag will irrefutably be used indistinctly for "MS Release Management" and "release management" in general, so it's better just to cut the problem instead of wasting time trying to enforce an specific usage, that could be used for something more productive and that requires attention.

Comment: It is just not the way questioners think about their problem.  They want to cast a wider net, letting more SO users see the question to increase the odds they find somebody that can help them.  And they assume that the *other* tags they use disambiguate.  They do.  Multiple tags have an OR function for finding help, an AND function for making it clear what the subject is.

Comment: @HansPassant 100% agree. I think renaming the [ms-release-management] tag to [release-management-vs] or [release-management-visual-studio] or [release-management-tfs] would be the best approach. Thoughts?

Comment: @HansPassant I see that you are an optimist, but I'm a reallist. That that you describe only happens in the 1% of the cases, which aren't worth the problems the rest 99% of the cases cause.